# Jekyll blog hosted in github: how to insert youtube embeddings?

Tags: youtube, jekyll, github-pages

I would like to be able to insert youtube videos in my Jekyll site hosted in Github.

- There is a Jekyll [plugin for embedding youtube videos](https://gist.github.com/joelverhagen/1805814) but it does not work in github pages.
- An iframe does not work either.

  ```
  <iframe width="420" src="hhtp://..." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
  ```

Is there a way to do it or we just have to live with that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try :

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: It works! Is it because of the `www.youtube.com/embed`url?

Comment: Yes. That's the embed code you can find on any youtube video page.

Comment: Doesn't work: `Refused to display https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'`. As far as I know GitHub doesn't allow foreign-origin iframes and it seems that even locally-ran Jekyll doesn't allow these. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Actually, it works. Just ensure that `/embed/` exists in the uri.

Answer (score 3):

One minor addition to the response of @David Jacquel:
the secure `https` is crucial for it to work in Github Pages (whereas the not secure `http` might be enough for it to work locally).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get the HTML directly from youtube.

Simply

1. Go to the youtube video you'd like to embed.
2. Click SHARE.
3. Click Embed.